# new branch with changes made while being on master without commiting?

Tags: git

I started working on master instead of creating new branch. I have not made any commit. How should I proceed if I want new branch from master but with all the changes I arleady made, but without commiting  it to master?

Comment: `git checkout -b <new_branch_name>` seems working;)

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing should do the trick too

Comment: Stashing would work, but it is unnecessary here.

Comment: Please avoid answering in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't committed, you're fine. Just branch and commit.

```
git checkout -b FeatureBranch
git add --all
git commit
```